# prevent filesystem from entering read-only mode

Tags: raid, filesystems, read-only, failed

I have found that my server's filesystem is continuously entering read-only mode.  There have been some issues with the raid1 array, but I have removed the bad disk from the array.  However, it is still physically plugged into the system because I haven't had a chance to go over to the datacentre, I suspect udev and the system kernel is still picking up the bad disk and throwing errors.  In /var/log/messages, there are errors like this:

```
Mar  2 06:53:14 nocloud kernel: ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
Mar  2 06:53:14 nocloud kernel: ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
Mar  2 06:53:14 nocloud kernel: ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
Mar  2 06:53:14 nocloud kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
Mar  2 06:53:20 nocloud kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar  2 06:53:21 nocloud kernel: ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Mar  2 06:53:21 nocloud kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar  2 06:53:21 nocloud kernel: ata1: EH complete
```

This happens fairly randomly throughout the day until eventually the filesystem becomes read-only.  When this happens, my system becomes non-operational which kind of defeats the purpose of having a raid1.  Note, ata1 is the bad disk (I think ata1 corresponds to /dev/sda because they are both first in line).

Under mdadm, /dev/sda1,2 is no longer being used, but I can't prevent the system kernel from continuing to query that disk when I am no longer using it and throwing these errors.

Is there a way to prevent my filesystem from automatically going into read-only mode? Furthermore, is it safe to do so?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Additional information:
output from cat /proc/mdstat

```
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      976554876 blocks super 1.1 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 5/8 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      204788 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]
```

Output from mount:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol00 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

EDIT2:
pvdisplay output:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/md1
VG Name               VolGroup
PV Size               931.32 GiB / not usable 2.87 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               16.00 MiB
Total PE              59604
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          59604
```

Comment: could you post the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mount` as well please? The additional info is needed as usually a filesystem's status would not be affected by an unrelated disk

Comment: i added this information into the original post, thanks for your help.

Comment: And now a `pvdisplay`, please. We still can`t see how you use **md1**.

Comment: I have edited my first post to include the pvdisplay output.

Answer (score 1):

Ext3/4 file systems (not sure about ext2) can be configured to flip to read only when they detect an error of some form, but there is usually a message similar to "EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting file system read-only" in your logs when this happens.

What does [tune2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) show you?  Run `tune2fs -l /dev/md1` to list the file systems current values.  The setting your looking for is "Errors behavior". [tune2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) can be used to change the error behavior, but you really should replace the drive before you have issues with the second drive.

Comment: So, when I tried to run that command, I got the following error message: tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md1.  Any ideas?

Comment: First thing to do: take an immediate backup. Ext3/4 file systems can get in bad states after hardware failure.  Even though RAID should protect you, weird things can happen. If the file system is entering read only mode, that's a warning that at a minimum you need to fsck it.  Worse case, you may need to rebuild it.  Rerun your tune2fs to point to /dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol00 instead of md1 and see what that says.

Comment: I retried the tune2fs -l command pointing to /dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol00 and this time, the command ran properly.  Errors behavior is set to Continue so this is not what is causing the filesystem to remount as read-only. However, I noticed that for Filesystem state, I have clean with errors.  Could this be part of the problem?